# Inserting Larger numbers in Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

can anybody please tell me which datatype is suitable for inserting larger numbers in SQlite? I want to insert number in more then 10 digits ,so need help

Comment: You have stated the minimum, whats the maximum size?

Comment: there isnt a data type like big int or long int ?

Comment: or you can use text data type

Comment: ok thanks for your suggestion